# Display Items Using Grid in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin Forms(Android,IOS,Windows).
I trying to display items in a grid with selection (highlight the selected item). 
Please find the below image for more information.

[image]

Can any one suggest me, How to achieve items display in grid with selection?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? It is generally better received when you ask about an issue you have run into as opposed to a general "how can I do this" question. That being said, it would be easy to make a grid with a relative or absolute layout in it to show an image on top of another image and then change the background color when an item is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

Generally each item binds a model which contains a boolean value that keeps selected or not. With that approach you ca initialize them as you want. Then create Gesture recognizer for tapping gesture & use Trigger for selection effect(BackgroundColor)

(In your definiton you mentioned to using inside Grid, so I'm not offering new methodology for UI hierarchy)

**Here is theCode:**

**Model:**

```
public Class ItemModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
// implement  INotifyPropertyChanged interface

    public ItemModel()
    {
        ToggleCommand = new Command(CmdToggle);
    }

    private void CmdToggle()
    {
        IsSelected = !IsSelected;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set; //call OnPropertyChanged
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get;
        set; //call OnPropertyChanged
    }

    public ICommand ToggleCommand{get;private set;}

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public Class PageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public List<ItemModel> Items
    {
        get;
        set; //call OnPropertyChanged
    } 
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
            return ((bool)value) ? Color.Gray: Color.White;


        else
            throw new NotSupportedException();
}

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="SelectedColor">Gray</Color/>
    <Color x:Key="UnselectedColor">White</Color/>
    <namespace:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter"/> 
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!--Single item -->
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               BindingContext="{Binding Items[0]}"
               Orientation="Vertical"
               BackgroundColor="{Binding IsSelected,Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"
>

    <Image Source="{Binding yourImageProperty}" />
    <Image Source="{Binding yourImage2Property}" />
    <Label Source="{Binding Name}"/>

  <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ToggleCommand}" />
  </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
  <!--Triggers will update background color when update IsSelected-->
  <StackLayout.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource SelectedColor}" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="c:Label" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="False">
      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource UnselectedColor}" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </StackLayout.Triggers>

  </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```